# Do they make a pull-chain type outlet adapter for garage door openers to plug in to?

Tags: electrical

I have constant power going to both my garage door openers. What I'm trying to do is come up with a way to easily cut power to them without having to get out and climb a small ladder to pull the power cords. I know they make the pull chains for lamp ceiling fixtures, I was just wondering if they made an adapter with a pull chain to put between the garage door power cords and the ceiling outlets. Can anyone help or have a better idea?

Comment: Why do you want to constantly cut the power to the garage door?

Comment: @B Mitch - Anti theft protection? :)

Comment: Also, many garage door openers will immediately turn on their light(s) when they receive power. In this case the switch to the garage door opener would also work in concert with the open/close button as a poor man's multi-function control.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a job for a light switch if you ask me.  If you don't want to tear up the walls, you can run the wire in some conduit along the ceiling and down the wall, placing the switch in a convenient location.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with B Mitch's answer as a good first and best method of switching off the power to the garage door opener.  If you don't want to run wires etc, you could replace the outlet that the opener plugs into with a keyless pull string light bulb holder. A keyless socket is like the ones you see in basements. It is a  simple 4 inch round porcelain   or plastic light fixture.  Instead of a bulb, you can screw in a plug adapter. All the parts you would need should cost less than $5.00

Answer (score 2):

This question isn't garage door specific. A simple solution would be to run an extension from somewhere you can access, and have a switch there.

I have my garage power switched through to a switch in the house so I can power it all down at night with one flick of a switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a pull switch some where in between the supply and the motor as lon as its rated to your current system 110/220VAC and 3-5AMP is ample. Make sure to have it earthed (if you have the earth available)

http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibeCCtpSctDspRte.jsp?section=13906&minisite=10026

http://cgi.ebay.com/Pull-Chain-Rotary-Appliance-Switch-3-Speed-2-Circuit-/390319237556?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5ae0d6e9b4#ht_3171wt_1139

There are multispet ones - so be carefull not to buy 3 speed (but you can merge all outputs to one if you want - you will jsut nned to pull the chain 3 times - or figure something more clever out)